# Add blank spaces in a string after some random digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I'm trying to add spaces to my input value while the user typing, it works for the constant digits like after 4 letters or after 5 letters. But I couldn't manage to add space after certain digits dynamically.

**for example**

if user types **1234567890**

blocks: **[3,3,4]**

expected output: **123 456 7890**

---

if user types **1234567890**

blocks: **[3,2,2,3]**

expected output is: **123 45 67 890**

Comment: you've tried anything ?

Comment: FYI: Changing the text are user types is always hard because of delete/backspace and cursor positioning.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey previously I used https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/ to achieve this which uses directives in Vue, but I didn't find a way to pass the blocks dynamically  to cleave.js while user is typing

Comment: @epascarello it doesn't stop sites that want my card information to do it. And more often than not, it leads to an utter disaster if I do anything other than continue typing. So, if I make a mistake and try to correct it, it gets ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Handling inputs as the user types can be tricky.

Although not perfect, one solution is to calculate what the expected result should be, and then compare with what it currently is.  If they are different then update the actual input with the calculated one.

Below is a simple example,.. It will even handle were the user pastes in the numbers.
One issue with the below is the cursor position if say you inserted the number mid way, but this could be maybe handled with remembering the cursor position and restoring.

```js
const splits = [3,3,4];
$('#a').on("input", function(){
  let count = 0;
  const breaks = splits.map(m => { const ret = m + count; count += m; return ret; });
  const a = this.value.split("").filter(f => f !== ' ');
  const s = a.map((m, ix) => {
    if (breaks.includes(ix + 1)) return m + " "
    else return m;
  }).join("");
  if (this.value.trim() !== s.trim()) this.value = s;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="a"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```js
function splitValue(value, index) {
    return value.substring(0, index) + " " + value.substring(index);
}
var test=[3,3,4];
var secondVar = '';
var firstVar = '1234567890';
for(let i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
  var TestVar = splitValue(firstVar, test[i]);
  secondVar = secondVar + " " + TestVar.split(" ")[0];
  secondVar=secondVar.trim();
  if(i == 0)
 firstVar = firstVar.replace(secondVar.trim(),'');
  else
  firstVar = firstVar.replace(secondVar.split(' ')[i + 1],'');
}
console.log(secondVar);
```